# User Identity Info

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-contrib

I've been messing around with creating my own implementation of an AspNet.Security.OAuthProviders by copying the GitHub example. Have a few questions..

First, I successfully authenticate but when I get back my User.Identity.Name is empty. I don't see that information coming back from my provider. Noob question I imagine, but do I have to explicitly request the information I want back? If so, how do I know what to ask for.. I'm kind of working blindly.

Second, in the GitHub example of the Handler, CreateTicketAsync immediately makes a call to the UserInformationEndpoint.  In my use case, after getting authorized I want to go to a page that has some links to some api requests that will use the acquired authorization, rather than do it right away.  I'm not sure if there is an example for that or I'm making incorrect assumptions and going about this the wrong way.

This is entirely supposed to be for demo purposes as a "how to" for other developers so I want to make sure I do things the correct way.